# npm run dev on next.js project successful but cannot reach the site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, windows-11

I'm working on a project with NextJS. I used create-next-app to create the repo. I ran the "npm run dev" in the terminal and it response "ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000". I turned on my browser, go to localhost:3000 on both Edge and Firefox but they both show error: cannot reach this page. How can I fix this? I'm on windows 11

I've tried delete .next and node_modules folder. It works but takes a while to install. I'm looking for a more long term solution if possible. Thank you